# Angular2 code doesn't lazy load module on production

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing

I am using the following starter pack from github https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter for my project and I am able to lazyload modules during development but on compiling the code for production, I am not able to access any of the routes properly without going to the root route.

Here is the routing configuration I am using on my root module.

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: SignInComponent,  pathMatch: 'full'  },
 { path: 'forgot-password', component:  ForgotPasswordComponent },
 {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: BaseComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      children: [
        {
          path: '', loadChildren: './+analytics/analytics.module#AnalyticsModule'
        },
        {
          path: 'teams', loadChildren: './+user/user.module#UserModule'
        },
   { path: '**', component: NoContentComponent }
];
```

Import on the root module

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false })
```

Here is the part for the webpack config that handles the ng-router

```
{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [{
                        loader: '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
                        options: {
                            pretty: !isProd,
                            prod: isProd
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ng-router-loader',
                        options: {
                            loader: 'async-import',
                            genDir: 'compiled',
                            aot: AOT
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: {
                            configFileName: 'tsconfig.webpack.json',
                            useCache: !isProd
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
                    }
                ],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
            },
```

I am unable to debug as to why the code doesn't work on production after bundling and minification. Any tips on how to debug this or solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Can you produce the prod build locally? Can you download the code that produced by your build system?

Comment: Do you mean that a refresh of the page causes error once you've put the dist on the server? Cuz if so you need to config the server to redirect all traffic to the index file.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz yes, I can access the root route and can access all the other routes by clicking them but cant access them directly

Comment: Then do what I told you to and it should work. You can google a simple htaccess file if using apache, not sure how to do it exactly with nginx or others.

Comment: Hey problem solved. I didn't realize that my nginx didn't have a location path. Thanks.